# Rotation does not match when converting vector and quaternion on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, quaternions

Please tell me the reason why the rotations of A and B do not match in the following code.

```
// Initial pose
transform.forward = (new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f)).normalized;
// Rotate 
transform.forward = (new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f)).normalized; // A
// convert quaternion
Vector3 fwd = transform.forward;
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), fwd);
transform.rotation = rot; // B
```

And how do match A/B rotations?

Answer (score 0):

Offical documentation for [FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) states

> Usually you use this to rotate a transform so that one of its axes eg. the y-axis - follows a target direction toDirection in world space.

And here

```
transform.forward = (new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f)).normalized;
```

we just assign the forward axis of transform to look diagnolly in X and Y.

Now

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), fwd);
```

This line will just create a rotation based on whatever side of `Transform` faces worlds forward and align it to the `fwd`. Well I know its parameters says `FromDirection` `ToDirection` but it is a bit ambiguous. It should have stated `FromAxis` `ToDirection`

Hence A not equals B